# subir imagenes multiples

Tags: php, mysql, html5, ajax, bootstrap

estoy trabajando un pequeño proyecto los trabajo clases/ control / JS
clases y JS en funciones pero tengo un inconveniente como puedo  guardar multipes imagenes sobre un empresa o un producto
alguien que me pueda ayudar ?
este con estas tablas se estaria trabajando

```
 CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `filesize` int NOT NULL,
  `web_path` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `system_path` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;



CREATE TABLE empres_files (
    `empresa_id` int NOT NULL,
    `file_id` int NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: ¿y qué has intentado? no creas que haremos todo tu trabajo, ¿ya tienes algún avance? ¿cuál es la duda?

Comment: no quiero que me lo hagan ustedes quiero un incio o un ejemplo para poder entender o una forma mas facil de realizar dicho trabajo mucho explican pero la hacen larga y me complica entender, pido ayuda no necesariamente para que lo resuelvan ustedes solo es un ejemplo como lo harian ustedes pueden recomendarme link's etc es mejor eso aque lo resuelvan ustedes